# Plugin with custom domain

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, domain

OK I will try to explane my problem better.

What I need to do is to create a kind o service for my WordPress.

From some external web sites I like to send some data to my main WordPress web site through the URL.

Lets say I have the web site http://www.mysite.ext/

On mysite.ext I will install my plugin.
Some external web sites can send my ocasionaly some data by a URL (ie: http://www.mysite.ext/getdata/data_are_here/)
In that case my plugin must recognize a query variable from the URL and analize the data

Note: It is not important to return any information to the external web sites. Just I have to collect the inrormation and process it.

Comment: You want to create that URL ... where exactly?  Is that a URL you want to print to the page, or a URL you want to be automatically rewritten by WordPress to interact with your plugin?  Is the domain the same as the site you're installing the plugin on?

Comment: Please describe little more and explain what you exactly want

Comment: You maybe want to take a look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more of my personal approach than any kind of best practice, but I find [WP's Ajax handler](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to be easy and logical endpoint for such technical URLs.